# Texworks made my code not work - I swear I didn't change anything?

Tags: math-mode, errors

I didn't change my code AT ALL except to add regular text at the bottom AFTER `$$`. And now nothing works properly. I get tons of stoppages/errors when i run my code and I have NO CLUE what the problem is here is one:

```
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   \displaystyle 
l.40 ...ell + \sum_{x=1}^{x=K}q_xs_x+$\displaystyle
                                                   \sum_{(\alpha, \sigma, t_...
```

what does this display math should end with `$$` mean?!?! the `$$` comes later!

```
$$t_f-t_0 = \ell + \sum_{x=1}^{x=K}q_xs_x+$\displaystyle \sum_{(\alpha, \sigma, t_z) \in \phi}$\hspace{-0.25}$\displaystyle Z_{\alpha\sigma}$(t)$\displaystyle \uplambda_{(\alpha,\sigma,t_z)}+H$$
```

Please tell me what is wrong with this I am so mad as I said that my code stopped working properly when i didn't even change anything. I get a bunch of errors by the way but this is just one of them.

Comment: Your snippet suggests you have plain TeX display math (`$$`) with inline math (`$`) inside it, which will give exactly the error you've posted: that's entirely independent of the editor you use.

Comment: CALM DOWN!!! ;-)

Comment: Could we please have a more informative example (MWE)?  Right now, I guess, the mixture of `$$`, `$` and commands like `\displaystyle` is rather a bad idea/habit.  (Sorry, to say, don't want to offend you.)

Comment: why blame the editor, that is not generating the error (that is tex) nor is it entering the clearly mis-matched math start/end (that is you)

Answer (score 6):

Jan has already shown corrected code, but to explain the error message.

You have

```
$$t_f-t_0 = \ell + \sum_{x=1}^{x=K}q_xs_x+$\displaystyle
```

TeX starts display math at the `$$` (which is not latex syntax and not mentioned in any latex manual)  so the `$` ends math but must be followed by another `$` so that it ends display math not inline math.

This is the error (which was *always* an error not anything texworks changed)
and is shown by TeX using a format shared by all TeX error messages:

```
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   \displaystyle 
l.40 ...ell + \sum_{x=1}^{x=K}q_xs_x+$\displaystyle
                                                   \sum_{(\alpha, \sigma, t_...
```

The first line starting with `!`describes the general error.

Then some specific information (`\displaystyle` token has been seen but it is not allowed here so it will be pushed back into the input and will be seen again after recovery from this error)

Then comes the context from the source, with the linebreak showing the point TeX reached (so it has not yet seen any text after the `\displaystyle`)

If you type `h` to the error prompt you get further information:

```
? h
The `$' that I just saw supposedly matches a previous `$$'.
So I shall assume that you typed `$$' both times.
```

so the `$` in your source is treated as `$$`.

You may as well stop here and fix the source as any later errors will be spurious, but if you carry on then you get

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
<to be read again> 
                   \displaystyle
```

Because the `$$` now finished the math, but the `\displaystyle` that was re-inserted earlier is only allowed in math so it generates a forced `$` to get back in to math mode and is again pushed back into the input, where it works.

Answer (score 4):

This should work -- and from my point of view, it should be clean code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  t_f-t_0 = \ell + \sum_{x=1}^{x=K}q_xs_x+
  \sum_{(\alpha, \sigma, t_z) \in \phi}
  Z_{\alpha\sigma}(t) \lambda_{(\alpha,\sigma,t_z)}+H
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `eq:7` as label name is possible, but I hope that equation and other label names are not numbered consecutively. Giving a unique, easy to remember name is less error-prone

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: again: you are so right.  It was inserted by emacs automatically. Maybe I have to have a frank word with it?

Comment: Emacs is to blame for this? `\let\emacs\vi` ???????

Comment: In that case, I won't be able to post that many answers any more, probably, I would procrastinate a lot more at vi.SE :-D

Comment: No, don't give in to the dark side of the force ;-)

Comment: At my hat you must look!